# How to dynamically add and remove form elements to an existing form based on selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm building a search form and don't want unused inputs to be included in my GET method. What is the best way to show inputs[fields] only whenever something is selected in select box? Can they be invisible in the DOM?

Comment: You can addClass/removeClass to the element that you want to be added to your request based on the selected value in selectbox. And while making a GET request, only select the "specific" class based on the selected value.

Comment: you have to show something what you have tried,  to get morespecific answer. Try to implement something your way then we ll solve whatever issue you are facing

Comment: I tried `show()` and `hide()` jquery functions, but the element/s are still in DOM. I don't want this, because Wordpress search form automatically grabs inputs and send them trought GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely based on assumptions:

```
if ($('#something').val() == 1) {
    // Show input
    $('#input_1').show();
} else {
    // Hide input
    $('#input_1').hide();

    // Remove if don't want to include in POST
    $('#input_1').remove();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var input_1 = '<input id="#input_1"/>';

if ($('#something').val() == 1) {
    // add input
    $('#addHere').append(input_1);
} else {
    // Remove input
    $('#input_1').remove();
}
```

Comment: That is perfect! But what happens, when the user toggled back his choise and that element can't be retrieved back. This could be really a problem. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: @destructor You have to call this function on choice change event. And if you want to remove elements, call the same function with remove before form submission.

Comment: I understood that @Tushar, thanks! My point is that this wasn't exaclly what I looked for. All I was trying to say is, that after `remove` function execudes, the field is gone and can't be brought back to DOM with this example, if the value of #something is changed.

Comment: Thank you @Tushar! That was exacly what I was looking for! Many thanks for that!